# C言語のbreakについて

Tags: c

下記のコードで、noが入力されたら終了するプログラムを組もうとしているのですが、止まらずに無限ループしてしまいます。
どこを修正したら良いでしょうか？

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    char op;
    float answer;
    int r,a;
    FILE* fp;
    int cnt = 0;

    fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ファイルオープン失敗\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    while (1) {
        r = scanf("%d%c%d", &num1, &op, &num2);
        if (r != 3) {
            puts("input error");
            return 1;
        }
        cnt++;

        if (op == '+') {
            answer = num1 + num2;
        }
        else if (op == '-') {
            answer = num1 - num2;
        }
        else if (op == '*') {
            answer = num1 * num2;
        }
        else if (op == '/') {
            answer = (float)num1 / num2;
        }

        time_t t = time(NULL);
        struct tm* tm = localtime(&t);
        printf("%d/%02d/%02d ", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday);
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d ", tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
        printf("%d%c%d,%f\n", num1, op, num2, answer);
        fprintf(fp, "%d/%02d/%02d ", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday);
        fprintf(fp, "%02d:%02d:%02d ", tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
        fprintf(fp, "%d%c%d,%f\n", num1, op, num2, answer);

        printf("計算を続けますか？");
        scanf("%s\n", &a);
        if (a == 'no') {
            break ;
        }
    }
        fclose(fp);
    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: コンパイルでエラーになると思うんですけど。釣りですか？

Comment: C の == は 文字列には使えません

Comment: シングルクォートなので文字列ですらない。

Comment: しかも aはint。C言語は免許制にすべきだと思います。

Comment: aの値がどうなっているか確かめましたか？

Comment: 「プログラムを組もう」という表現が気になる。学生じゃないのか。

Comment: @NorioYamamoto 学生で有ろうが無かろうが、質問して構いません。質問者の属性を云々するのはお止め下さい。
「釣りですか？」「免許制」なども、スタックオーバーフローにおけるコメントとして不適切です。
技術的な指摘も含まれているので、直ぐにモデレーター対応を求めることはしませんが、表現を改めて、別途コメントなり回答なりにまとめて戴きたいと思います。

Comment: Norio Yamamotoさんの表現が不適切な点についてはmjyさんの指摘に賛同します。ただし、質問者さん側にも原因があります。 [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) や [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) などを踏まえて質問文を書いていただく必要があります。例えば「関係のないエラー・警告は排除しておきましょう」とあります。排除されていないからこそ「コンパイルでエラーになると思うんですけど。」などの発言につながっていることは理解してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今のソースコードのままコンパイル・実行が出来るのなら、コンパイラに依存するかもしれませんが、その状態で「止まらずに無限ループ」していますか？

「入力(scanf()関数)が完了せず if 文の処理にたどり着いていない」状態ではありませんか？

そうではなくてもし`計算を続けますか？`の表示後に何か入力して、その後にループの先頭に戻って演算式の入力・処理が出来るなら、その次の`計算を続けますか？`の表示に対して`no`ではなく`on`を入力してみてください。

もしかしたら、それでループをbreakして終了するかもしれません。

その場合はC言語としては間違った(あるいは悪い振る舞いをする)プログラムのままですが、`if (a == 'no') {`の行を`if (a == 'on') {`というように`n`と`o`を逆にすれば、人間が`no`と入力した場合に終了するようになるはずです。

ヒントは文字定数`'no'`は`int`型の数値`0x00006e6f`として扱われるからですね。
そして今のソースコードで動作しているなら、`no`入力後の`a`の値は`0x00006f6e`である可能性があります。
なので、`on`と入力すると`a`の値が`0x00006e6f`となってbreak・終了する可能性があるわけです。

---

**とは言え、実際にはコメントが多数付いているように、C言語のプログラムとしては以下の点で間違っています。**

- scanf()関数で入力データの書式を示す文字列に`\n`が使われている。
  そうすると`\n`まで正確に入力する必要が出てくるので、ここでは不要。
  例えば [scanf関数](http://rainbow.pc.uec.ac.jp/edu/program/b1/Ex2-1b.htm) のページの最後を参照
- scanf()関数で入力データを格納する変数に`int`型の変数が使われている。
  文字列(`%s`)を格納するなら`char`型の配列で、十分なサイズを用意するべき。
- C言語で文字列(charの配列)が同じかどうかを比較するのに`==`は使えません。
  文字列の比較には[strcmp関数](https://www.orchid.co.jp/computer/cschool/CREF/strcmp.html)(大文字小文字を区別する)や[stricmp関数](https://www.orchid.co.jp/computer/cschool/CREF/stricmp.html)(大文字小文字を区別しない)等を使用する必要があります。
- 文字列を比較する際に比較用の固定文字列を記述するには、シングルクォーテーションは使えません。
  ダブルクォーテーションで囲む必要があります。

---

という訳で質問のソースコードから抜粋した以下の該当部分を：

```
    int r,a;

        scanf("%s\n", &a);
        if (a == 'no') {
```

こちらのように変更すれば良いでしょう。(`NO`も使えるように`stricmp`にしています)

```
    int r;
    char a[16]={0};

        scanf("%s", a);
        if (stricmp(a, "no") == 0) {
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Comment: @齋藤和輝 さん、今までの他の質問も含めて解決したなら承認のチェックをお願いします。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)